# image fit into canvas fabricjs

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

I am using Fabricjs for upload image with the current code

Image is showing only 1/4th of the full image.  It's not showing full image in a canvas in this tscode i am setting width and height of the image manually.

Here is my Ts code

```
  addImage(canvasInst, imageUrl) {
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, img => {
  var oImg = img.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  });
  var canvasWidth = canvasInst.width / canvasInst.getZoom();
  oImg.scaleToWidth(canvasWidth);
  canvasInst.add(oImg).renderAll();
  canvasInst.toDataURL({ format: "png", quality: 0.8 });
});
```

}

But i was trying other way scaletowidth but that is not working here

here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oekb88?file=package.json)

Example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FabricJS uses the properties `scaleX` and `scaleY` to determine the size of the image, while the `width` and `height` properties are used to specify how much of the original image dimensions should be used (shrinking these values will crop the image, not scale it).

In your linked example, you're running `scaleToWidth()` on the canvas. You need to run it on the image instead.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, img => {
  var oImg = img.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  });
  var canvasWidth = canvasInst.width / canvasInst.getZoom();
  oImg.scaleToWidth(canvasWidth);
  canvasInst.add(oImg).renderAll();
});
```

Comment: this is not coming in center

Comment: fitting the image is just a matter of scaling it to the width of the canvas. I'll update my answer to show you.

Comment: Yes pls i am waiting

Comment: i updated with your code but still the image is not in center

Comment: if you my question i updated with your code